# Can't escape pipe character in windows CMD when echoing?

Tags: cmd, pipe, plink

I am trying to pipe some commands via echo to plink over serial comport to a linux device.  Most short commands work, but when I combined with a linux command that needs a pipe character "|" it breaks.  Which makes sense, since cmd or echo thinks its a cmd commands it is trying to pipe to.  I tried using 
"^|" to escape the pipe character but its not working.

I tried:

```
echo ble_util | head -n 10 | plink -serial COM17 -sercfg 115200
'head' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Again, makes sense since cmd thinks I am trying to pipe into head...but then I try:

```
echo ble_util ^| head -n 10 | plink -serial COM17 -sercfg 115200
'head' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Same issue, only difference is that the control is not returned to cmd, I have to ctrl+c to be able to gain back control.

Then I tried:

```
echo ble_util ^| head -n 10 ^| plink -serial COM17 -sercfg 115200
ble_util | head -n 10 | plink -serial COM17 -sercfg 115200
```

And obviously that works.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try replacing cmd `echo` with PowerShell `echo`? `powershell -command "echo 'echo aaa | grep aaa'" | plink ...`?

Comment: Your 1st and 2nd example should behave differently. You might try `echo ble_util ^^^| head -n 10 | plink -serial COM17 -sercfg 115200`

Comment: @LotPings I can confirm the behavior the OP is seeing (on Windows 10).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl With or without a head in my local path, with escaped `^|` I get a `'plink' is not recognized as an internal or external command`, so I'm a bit at a loss what's happening (WIn10Pro)

Comment: @LotPings It's processed from the end. So it first stops on `plink` (if you do not have it). But replace `plink` with anything you have (simple `echo`) and you will get an error on `head`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl You've got a point, but my double escaping seems to work because with `echo ble_util ^^^| head -n 10 | findstr "."` I get the whole piped string.

Comment: @LotPings Indeed, it might work. I was not objecting that :)

Comment: Windows does not have a `head` command. What `head` are you using?

Comment: @lit I believe, OP wants to send `ble_util | head -n 10` as a literal string/input to `plink` (to be executed on a connected Linux device).

Comment: Hi all, sorry out sick yesterday.  Will give the triple escape character a try and see what's going on.  Any idea why I need to escape it that many times?  Appreciate the help.